# IQueryable and Mixing Lazy Loading and Eager Loading

Tags: entity-framework, repository, lazy-loading, iqueryable, eager-loading

I have a situation where I will be using a repository pattern and pulling objects from the database with a lazy loaded GetAll method that returns IQueryable. However I also need to build dynamic objects that will be included with the lazy loaded objects(query).

Is it possible to add built objects to a lazy loaded IQueryable and still keep the lazy loaded benefits? For instance

```
public override IQueryable<Foo> GetAll()
{
    return _entities; // lazy loaded
}  

public override IQueryable<Foo> GetAllPlusDynamic()
{
    var entities = GetAll(); 
    foreach(var d in GetAllDynamic())
    {
        entities.Add(d); // eagerly loaded
    }
    return entities;
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question. What are those "dynamic objects" which are "eagerly loaded"? Do you mean some kind of `Include` expression, like in `Include(customer => customer.Orders)`, or so? Can you make some concrete example?

Comment: @Slauma my understanding was that Op wanted *GetAllPlusDynamic* to query the database collection *plus* some other collection...

Comment: Yes, basically query the database for a set of objects and then query another data source (in this case a service) and build a set of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if I understand you correctly but refering to your comment...

> Yes, basically query the database for a set of objects and then query
>   another data source (in this case a service) and build a set of
>   objects.

... I would say that it's not possible.

An object of type `IQueryable<T>` used with Entity Framework (LINQ to Entities) is basically a description of a query which the underlying data store can execute, usually an abstract description (expression tree) which gets translated into SQL.

Every part of such a query description - `where` expressions, `select` expression, `Any(...)` expressions, etc. - must be translatable into the native language (SQL) of the data store. It's especially not possible to include some method calls - like a service call - in an expression that the database cannot understand and perform.

`IQueryable<T>` knows an underlying "provider". This provider is responsible to translate the expression tree hold by the `IQueryable<T>` object into "something", for example T-SQL used by SQL Server, or the SQL dialects used by MySQL or Oracle. I believe it's possible to write your own provider which might then be able to perform somehow the service calls and the database queries. But I also believe that this is not an easy task.

Using the standard SQL providers for Entity Framework you have to perform database query and calling the service separately one after each other: Run query and materialize entities in memory - then run the service call on the result collection for each entity.